# Fields are empty mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with my code, REQUIRED make if the inputs are empty will not execute anything in the database, and send a message that should fill all fields've investigated all day but I can not give solution hope someone can help me.

How could I do that if the fields are empty send a message that says error and does not execute anything in the database.

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="")
{
 header("Location: me.php");
}
include_once 'sistema/config.web.php';

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
 $email = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_email']));
 $upass = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));

 $query = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail='$email'");
 $row=$query->fetch_array();

 if(password_verify($upass, $row['password']))
 {
  $_SESSION['userSession'] = $row['id'];
  header("Location: me.php");
 }
 else
 {
  $msg = "Email o contraseña no encontrados";
 }

 $MySQLi_CON->close();

}

if(isset($_POST['btn-signup']))
{
$uname = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_name']));
$email = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_email']));
$upass = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['password']));
$new_password = password_hash($upass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$check_email = $MySQLi_CON->query("SELECT mail FROM users WHERE mail='$email'");
$count=$check_email->num_rows;
if($count==0){
$query = "INSERT INTO users(username,mail,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$new_password')";
if($MySQLi_CON->query($query))
{
$msge = "Registrado correctamente";
}
else
{
$msge = "Eror al registrarte";
}
}
else{
$msge = "Email en uso";
}
$MySQLi_CON->close();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn-signup'])) {

     $uname = $MySQLi_CON->real_escape_string(trim($_POST['user_name']));
     $email = ......
     $upass = ......

     /* Modified code starts */

     $valid = true;

     if(empty($uname)) {
         $msge[] = "Username is required.";
         $valid = false;
     } if(empty($email)) {
         $msge[] = "email is required.";
         $valid = false;
     } if(empty($upass)) {
         $msge[] = "Password is required.";
         $valid = false;
     }

     /* Modified code ends */

     $new_password = ......
     $check_email =....
     $count = ....

     /* Modified code starts again */

     if ($count > 0) {
       $msge[] = "Email en uso";
       $valid = false;
     }

     if ($valid) {

          $query = "INSERT INTO users(username,mail,password) VALUES('$uname','$email','$new_password')";
          if ($MySQLi_CON->query($query)) {
             $msge = "Registrado correctamente";
          } else {
               $msge = "Eror al registrarte";
          }
      }

     $MySQLi_CON->close();
  }
```

Finally, print the alert message:

```
echo implode('<br/>', $msge);
```